# How to change the height of video stream in SignalWire video api

Tags: javascript, css, signalwire

Hi all I am using Signalwire's video calling functionality to make a video calling app. I am facing one issue here, as most of the times, we use video calling through phones or small screen sizes the height of the video is very small there.
Is there any way to increase the height of that div on which the video stream is getting injected?
Here What it looks like-

[image]

In mobile my video screen is quite small I want to increase the height.
I tried something like-

```
$scope.roomObject = new SignalWire.Video.RoomSession({
 token: token,
 rootElement: document.getElementById('root'), // an html element to display the video
 audio: true,
  video: {
    width: { min: 720},
    height: { min: 1280}
  }
}


});
```

This does change the inner video into portrait mode but the issue remains, I can't increase the height.
Note- increasing the height of div not working I can increase the width though.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to extend the video canvas vertically to fill the entire screen. While you can change the aspect ratio of your video stream itself (which is how you're swapping your stream to portrait), you can't change the aspect ratio of the whole canvas.